# Fail to Download File Using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter

I've used above link for reference.

I'm Using **Save Responses to a file** with Download call.
But fail to Download file.

Can anyone tell me What Exactly i need Specify in

**FileName Prefix:**

**Variable name :**

and **where to Specify download location** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide absolute file path with a file name.

```
FileName Prefix: c:\workspace\jmeter-download\myfile
```

For ex: If your test is downloading a pdf file, you would see a 'myfile.pdf' under 'c:\workspace\jmeter-download'

Answer (score 0):

I've used path like  **D:/xyzFolder/filename** as Filename Prifix

it's working fine for me

and if any one wants file to download in same Dir in which your jmx file is

then just need to use **~/pre**  as Filename Prifix